# Logic Apps - Data Operations Parse JSON not parsing Content from Event Hub

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-eventhub

I am trying to create a logic app that connects to event hub and sends an email whenever an event is added to the event hub.

I was able to get it working when connecting EH to outlook connectors. I want to be able to parse the data and extract certain fields from the event content. I look up online to use Parse JSON  from the Data Operations action but it seems not to be able to parse the content
[image]

I tried using Body as the input and it succeeds but the event fields are empty, indicating me that it not getting the event data.

Any ideas?

Comment: Content seems to be a base64 URL encoded string. Try to decode it and check if JSON object is vaalid.

Comment: Is there a way to decode content in logic apps?

Comment: Content subject to failure is already in the error message you shared. Can you try decoding that?

Comment: Yes I decoded it and it worked, added expression to decode content 
`json(base64ToString(triggerBody()?['ContentData']))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a test and reproduce your problem, suppose your `content-type` is `application/octet-stream`, if yes the content will be encoded with base64, then the `Parse_JSON` input content should be `decodeBase64(triggerBody()?['ContentData'])`.

[image]

[image]

Also you could change the `content type` to `application/json` or `text/plain`, it will just work.

[image]